# a little script messes up wordpress blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this script to display recent posts:

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<li><?php the_content_limit(250); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

I put this in the header.php. It does the job, but also all other posts and pages gets messed up. When I try to load any ordinary page (page.php) I get only content from two blog posts and similar problems. It is not the issue with the_content_limit. I also tried excerpt - and its the same.

Any ideas how to avoid the problem but still have recent posts?

Comment: Messes up how?  What are you trying to do?  Read the FAQ before posting here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Actually he gets duplicate content on the same page but he did not explain that well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not put `query_posts` in header usually. Try making a new file to include there and before new querys use this `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`